# Import statement not working anymore (dart with Flutter on VS Code)

Tags: flutter, dart, import

I am suddenly not able to import any flutter package on VS Code anymore, whose 'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';'
The statement is even showed in 'red'... as blue when it works!

Does anyone has a clue?

Thank you so much by advance! :)

I tried to to each repair, and put get, but I didn't fixed anything.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaXZ5.png)

Comment: import your audio package

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi! thank you for replying! I don't know what happened, I just had to turn off and on the app.. it's now working